# Which ports to open on the firewall for this FTP client connection?

Tags: firewall, ftp, port

I'm using for the first time today https://github.com/veeso/suppaftp and I'm super happy.

On my local machine everything works.
On production machine it does not.
On production machine there is a firewall and I don't know which which ports to be open.

Let's say I'm using the passive mode (by default) I think I need to open the port 21 at least.
And in fact it works **partially**: it creates directories an files but do not send any data.

What other port(s) do I need?

Comment: Easy way would be to check the firewall log to see what was being rejected or dropped when the FTP server starts up and when an incoming connection occurs. Likely explanation for why it works on a local machine is because of UPnP, which should _never_ be used since there is no secure implementation of UPnP _(port forwarding should always be manually configured)_. For example, adding a DNAT allow rule for the specific FTP port and the specific IP and MAC of the device it's going to that the server is running on, as well as any other rules required

Comment: Active FTP generally uses TCP port 20 (for data) and 21 (for control) on the server side by default, which would explain why only the data transfer isn't working. Depending on your environment, some firewalls may only block FTP traffic once it starts transferring data, rather than block the ports outright

Comment: do users login to your ftp server? it seems weird that there would be a firewall issue that impacted the service this way, unless the firewall is performing egress filtering that is blocking response traffic.